# Big Endian mixed Little Endian

Tags: operating-system, system

What is the logic behind the case when Big Endian mixed with Little Endian.

For example, we have a value 0x10203040 and the following order.

> 0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
>
> 40    10    20    30

Answer (score 1):

The only time you have a mix of little- and big-endian is when you exchange data between system or store data in a format that is used to exchange data.

Otherwise, you never work with big- and little-endian data at the same time.